# How to first get different related values from different SQL tables (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, request

I am triig to fill options list. I have 2 tables USERS and STREAMS I vant to get all streams and get names of users assigned to that streams.

Users consists of username and id

Streams consists of id, userID, streamID

I try such code:

```
<?php           
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * 
        FROM streams ";
        $streams_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($streams_set);    
    $streams_count = mysql_num_rows($streams_set);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($streams_set)){
            $userid = $row['userID'];
                global $connection;
        $query2 = "SELECT email, username ";
        $query2 .= "FROM users ";
        $query2 .= "WHERE id = '{$userid}' ";

        $qs = mysql_query($query2, $connection);
        confirm_query($qs); 
        $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($qs);


 echo ' <option value="'.$row['streamID'].'">'.$row['userID'].$found_user.'</option> ';
}
    ?>
```

But it does not return USER names from DB=( So what shall I do to this code to see usernames as "options" text?

Comment: Just to be sure what you're trying to do: Can each user only be on one stream?

Comment: There's an endless loop in your code.If you want the while statement to be the loop you want,you should write that as @VolkerK did.

Comment: @SpawnCxy: Though I encourage people to write the loop condition like I do ;-) it should work as intended like Ole wrote it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one query containing a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp) on streams.userID=users.id

```
$query = "
  SELECT
    s.streamId,
    s.userId,
    u.username
  FROM
    streams as s
  JOIN
    users as u
  ON
    s.userId=u.id
  ";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($result);
echo '<option value="">Debug: #rows=', mysql_num_rows($row), '"</option>';

while ( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) ) {
  sprintf('<option value="%s">id:%s name:%s</option>',
    $row['streamID'], // you probably should apply htmlspecialchars()
    $row['userID'], // on these two, too.
    htmlspecialchars($row['username'])
  );
}
```

Comment: BTW there are some errors in your code about beeg or small leters (  s.streamId ->  $row['streamID'])

Comment: Most of the time I test the code I post, sometimes not  ....like in this case ;-) sorry.